# finding max of two numbers on button click

Tags: javascript, html, forms, function

I am pretty new to HTML and JavaScript, and am trying a homework task.

There is a form with two fields where the user enters numbers, and a button. When the button is pressed, the max of the two numbers should be displayed.

As it is, the output is NaN, but I don't know why. I have run it through the chrome debugger, and at the line `var1 = parseInt(var1);`, var1 has value NaN. The same happens on the next line.

If I replace each line with something like `var1 = parseInt("6");`, this doesn't happen and everything behaves as expected (although obviously not doing what I need).

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
<html>
<head>
  <title> Question 2 </title>
  <script>
  function larger(var1,var2) {
    var1 = parseInt(var1);
    var2 = parseInt(var2);
    var max = var1>var2 ? var1 : var2;
    return max;
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <label>First number:</label> <input type="text" name="num1"/><br/>
        <label>Second number:</label> <input type="text" name="num2"/><br/>
        <input type="button" value="Compute" onclick="myResult.value=larger(num1,num2)"/>
        <input type="text" name="result" id="myResult"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where are `num1` and `num2` defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<body>
    <form>
        <label>First number:</label> <input type="text" name="num1"/><br/>
        <label>Second number:</label> <input type="text" name="num2"/><br/>
        <input type="button" value="Compute" onclick="myResult.value=larger()"/>
        <input type="text" name="result" id="myResult"/>
    </form>
</body>

function larger() {    
    var1 = parseInt(document.getElementsByName('num1'));
    var2 = parseInt(document.getElementsByName('num2'));
    var max = var1>var2 ? var1 : var2;
    return max;
}
```

Comment: Since the OP is just learning JS, it would help if you padded your question with a description of what you've done.

Comment: It's nice idea to always add some description to posted code.

Comment: Thanks, that actually clears up quite a lot for me. But if you wanted to add some description I won't complain ;)

Comment: Just to clarify what's going on, why does it not work if I change the method call rather than the method itself, using `myResult.value=larger(parseInt(document.getElementsByName('num1')), parseInt(document.getElementsByName('num2')))` for the button's onclick?

Answer (score 0):

Your function don´t get the values from the HTML. You don´t need to parameterize your function. You can read the values inside your function like:

```
    var1 = document.getElementById('someId');
```

And add an id="someId"-Tag to your input field.

Comment: But the text box does not have id's. They need to be fetched by name. :)

Comment: Yes thats another option ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are doing very wrong here: because you call function like this: `onclick="myResult.value=larger(num1,num2)"`

It's not correct, because if you want to get value of `num1` and `num2`, you need to use javascript method `document.getElementsByName` .

In you case you can use :

```
var num1Value = document.getElementsByName(num1);
var num2Value = document.getElementsByName(num2);
```

[document.getElementsByName](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementsbyname.asp)

Second thing, you use `parseInt()` method which used to parses a string and returns an integer.

[ParseInt()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You may change the function as follows

```
function larger(var1,var2) {
    var1 = document.getElementsByName("num1");
    var2 = document.getElementsByName("num2");
    var max = var1>var2 ? var1 : var2;
    return max;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Since the getElementsByName() returns array of nodes. So you have to get the value of text box by following method :

```
<body>
     <form>
         <label>First number:</label> <input type="text" name="num1"/><br/>
         <label>Second number:</label> <input type="text" name="num2"/><br/>
         <input type="button" value="Compute" onclick="myResult.value=larger()"/>
         <input type="text" name="result" id="myResult"/>
     </form>
</body>
<script>
     function larger() {
         var1 = parseInt(document.getElementsByName("num1")[0].value);
         var2 = parseInt(document.getElementsByName("num2")[0].value);
         var max = var1>var2 ? var1 : var2;
         return max;
     }
</script>
```